Terraform use variable in array
I created a resource for a random password like this:
    resource "random_password" "secret1" {
      length = 12
      special = false
      numeric = true
    }

I want to use the result of this in an array 'fields' in tfvars file:
fields = [
    {
      fieldname = "Username"
      itemvalue = "terraform"
    },
    {
      fieldname = "Password"
      itemvalue = random_password.secret1.result
    }
  ]

This throws an error:
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on terraform.tfvars line 17:
│   17:       itemvalue = random_password.random_secret.result
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
How can I achive to use the result of the random_password as itemvalue as I don´t want to use a static value.

You cannot do that. The tfvars files are static files, i.e, the values need to be known beforehand. If you were to provide information on how you are using the fields variable, maybe someone could provide an answer.

You cannot reference anything in tfvars those are static value files, as @Marko E pointed out in its comment.
A path forward to achieve your goal could be to rethink you you define your fields variable as I'll explain below.
Fist, refactor the variable's definition to allow you to choose which entry you want to generate and which you want to statically set
variable "fields" {
  type = list(object({
    field_name             = string
    field_value            = optional(string)
    randomically_generated = optional(bool, false)
  })
}

Change your tfvars accordingly:
  fields = [
    {
      field_name = "Username"
      item_value = "terraform"
    },
    {
      field_name             = "Password"
      randomically_generated = true
    }
  ]

Generate a random value for each field that has randomically_generated set to true:
resource "random_password" "generated" {
  for_each = {
    # we use the field_name as the key (I'm assuming it is unique)
    f in var.fields : field_name => f if randomically_generated
  }
  length  = 12
  special = false
  numeric = true
}

Use a local value to generate your final structure which will mix provided and randomically generated values:
locals {
  fields = [
    for f in fields: {
      field_name  = f.field_name
      field_value = f.randomically_generated ?
        # select the value generated for that field, or the value if not generated
        random_password.generated[f.field_value].result : f.field_value
    }
  ]
}

In the places in which you needed to use var.fields you'll use instead local.fields.
P.S. I've tried to follow your current fields definition which is an array, but maybe a map (indexed by field_name) would be a better approach (see references).

References:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each (for_each use)
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals (local values)
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/howto-filter-element-of-map/4434/4 (map/array filtering)
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes (optional explained)
https://spacelift.io/blog/terraform-map-variable (how to use map variables)
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#custom-validation-rules (bonus, you could add a validation rule to enforce that either randomically_generated or field_value are set, but not both)


Okay, thanks for your hint with the locals! I found a solution for this which looks similar to the one in the example :-)
